# Low-side 12V gate voltage driver required for non-PWM application?

Tags: mosfet, relay, power-electronics, mosfet-driver

Do I require a gate driver IC to turn on my MOSFET BSS138, if I supply 12 V DC to the gate of the MOSFET?

The MOSFET is NOT being used to switch a PWM waveform. It is simply being used to turn on and off a relay. It will most probably be switched on once a day and once off a day. I have connected it has a low-side switch configuration.

Since 12 V DC at the input is sufficient to turn on the MOSFET I assume I will not need a gate driver IC, is this correct?

The relay coil is specified for a 24 V DC input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKbFVZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The only problem I see is how you are going to switch it on more times than you turn it off.

Comment: I deleted my comment about that because I didn't want to distract from the schematic but...I really hope it is not an editing artifact and there is an interesting answer behind it. But I think it is an editing issue.

Comment: I also deleted my comment because I did not read the datasheet details.

Comment: @GTElectronics in deed that was an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit is perfectly designed for your needs.

Just make sure your relay's coil draws less than 220mA (unlikely that it draws more but check).